# htaccess - How can I redirect all ".php" pages to "/" pages?

Tags: .htaccess

My URLs look like this:

```
mywebsite.com/subpage-name.php
```

I want my new links to look like this:

```
mywebsite.com/subpage-name/
```

How can I redirect all my ".php" pages to "/" pages?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a RewriteRule in your .htaccess with a regex.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.thenewdomain.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

Make sure to add

```
RewriteEngine on
```

Before applying the redirect rule.

Happy Coding.

Comment: THe domain would stay the same. I only want to change the ending of the links from .php to /